# Doctype and Quirk modes and HTML 5

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, doctype, quirks-mode

I am having quite a horrible time. We have a massive site that has no `<DOCTYPE>` and when I run it with IE10 it goes into quirks mode and after some CSS changes looks ok. As soon as I add `echo "<!DOCTYPE HTML>";`

The complete site looks terrible and the CSS is not looking as it suppose to. It turns the browser mode to IE10 and docmode to standard. Is there a way to keep HTML 5 functionality but use IE5 Quirks mode or just Quirks mode so the CSS will look correct?

Comment: Why did you tag this [google-chrome] when your question seems to be about IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The whole point of quirks mode is that it's a compatibility mode for IE5. This means that in addition to changing the layout mode, it also switches off most of the browser features that have been invented since IE5.

Therefore the blunt answer is no, you cannot mix Quirks mode and HTML5. It just can't happen.

However there is some good news for you: switching from quirks mode to standards mode is actually easier than it looks at first glance.

You don't have to go through your whole site changing all the CSS to suit the different box model, because standards mode does have a CSS feature that allows you to use the quirks mode box model while still remaining in standards mode.

Simply add the following to the top of your CSS code:

```
* {box-sizing:border-box;}
```

This will change all your elements to use the quirks mode box model, but your page will still be in standards mode.

This should sort out most (if not all) of the layout issues you've been having.

Hope that helps.

Comment: HTML5 features work in Quirks Mode, too. And moving from Quirks Mode to Standards Mode is *far* more complicated than it may look like.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: I disagree. A lot of stuff dosn't work in Quirks. I don't have a full list, and I know it varies between browsers, but specifically in IE a lot is missing, largely because all CSS2/CSS3 features are removed and also many JS APIs. Also, the `box-sizing` solution I've given *does* deal with the main box model issue (that's really the whole reason `box-sizing` exists), and since this was specifically what the OP was struggling with, I don't see why you've downvoted me. In any case, OP has accepted the answer, so one would hope that means he's tried it and it worked for him.

Comment: Can you mention a single *HTML5 functionality* (which is what the question was about) that is affected by the presense or absence of a `doctype` string?

Comment: Well just to satisfy us both, I just tried [a simple `<canvas>` demo](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-linear-gradients/) in IE11 with the doctype removed. Complete fail; no canvas at all, because the whole canvas API doesn't exist in quirks mode. So that's one major HTML5 feature that's not there. I could repeat for others if you like.

Comment: In IE 10, there is no problem with the canvas demo in Quirks Mode. Please provide more information about HTML functionality features that are affected by Quirks/Standards mode in IE 11. It is important to know these, if IE 11 is really breaking things that badly.

Comment: @Spudley - I ran the same test in IE10 and it displayed just fine. (don't have IE11). But the lack of a doctype caused the page to handled in the modern IE10 quirks mode (consistent with the quirks mode of Chrome and Firefox) and not the IE5 quirks mode available through the developer tools. Forcing the IE5 quirks mode, I get the same complete fail as you did.

Comment: This isn't really the right place to discuss it and I don't have time to go into much more detail. But I testing that page in IE11 gives mixed results. By default in the absence of a doctype it goes into IE5 Quirks mode. When in this mode the canvas feature does not work. But IE11 does seem to *sometimes* put that page into standards mode regardless of the missing doctype (it issues a console warning instead). This behaviour wasn't consistent between page loads, but maybe it's detecting the use of HTML5 features? NB: IE11 does not allow switching modes manually if page loads in standards mode.

Comment: OK, I now tested on (real) IE 9, and in its Quirks Mode, `canvas` element is not recognized. So in the absence of `DOCTYPE`, *some* HTML5 features may fail in some versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. The modern engine that includes the new features and the engine for emulating ancient, buggier browsers are separate entities and you can't mix and match parts of them.

Answer (score 0):

As far as browsers other than IE are considered, you can add tags and attributes introduced in HTML5, without using any `<!DOCTYPE>`. The page will not conform to HTML5 then, but this is just a formality as such. Browsers do what they do, interpreting tags and attributes as they have been programmed to. There is no “HTML5 mode” in browsers that you would need to trigger with a `<!DOCTYPE>` or otherwise. Just try it. Throw in some HTML5 novelties like `<input type=email>` or `<details>`, and you will see that they work if the browser supports them in the first place, no matter whether there is a `<!DOCTYPE>` or not.

You would then have difficulties when using a markup validator, but that’s a different issue.

[Quirks Mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html) is a real mess, with dozens of undocumented and poorly documented phenomena. If a page works in Quirks Mode and you then make browsers render it in Standards Mode, literally anything may happen, ranging from no effect to total disaster. So such a change is usually pointlessly risky. Keep using Quirks Mode for old pages developed to use it, and create new pages to work in Standards Mode (and possibly to be HTML5 conformant).

Quirks Mode affects *styling* and to some extent scripting. It marginally affects the interpretation of some old HTML attributes. But in most browsers, not the way new HTML5 features work.

However, IE is particularly quirky. On IE 10, the above seems to apply. On IE 11 Preview, deviations have been reported. And on IE 9, some of HTML5 novelties that it would otherwise support are not supported in Quirks Mode, such as the `canvas` element. So if you intend to add *substantial* use of new HTML5 features to an old page that now works in Quirks Mode, you may need to consider changing the page to Standards Mode first. Depending on the impact of Quirks features, this might be best done by rewriting the page, or it might be “only” a matter of redesigning the use of CSS to conform to CSS specifications.

[Answer corrected Oct 15, 2013.]

Comment: before you think I did a revenge downvote, please note that it was not me.

Comment: I don’t care who downvoted, but I would love to see any of my statements here proven (or even claimed) wrong or irrelevant.

Comment: Actually HTML5's quirks mode, as opposed to the very different IE10's "IE5 quirks mode" is very well documented. Indeed, that's why HTML5 refers to "standards" mode as "no-quirks" mode, because "quirks" mode has been standardized. HTML5 features will work in HTML5 quirks mode, but not in "IE5 quirks mode". Confusing isn't it?