# line-height not being respected in some circumstances

Tags: css

Here's the html used to reproduce my problem:

```html
<div style="
    line-height: 100px;
    background: red;
"><div style="
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: green;
"></div>
</div>
```

In some cases, like within the above stackoverflow snippet view, it works as expected, and I get something like so:

[image: what i want]

---

however on my website it's display like below:

[image]

I've only managed to recreate this by running the below javascript which replaces the contents of a webpage -- done in chrome using the console, try it on this page:

```
document.write(`<html><head></head><body><div style="
    line-height: 100px;
    background: red;
"><div style="
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: green;
"></div>
</div></body></html>`);
```

What's weirder is that if you run this same script in a snippet, it works fine:

```js
document.write(`<html><head></head><body><div style="
    line-height: 100px;
    background: red;
"><div style="
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: green;
"></div>
</div></body></html>`);
```

---

What's the difference between the two scenarios, and what's actually going on?

Comment: It's going to be very difficult for anyone to answer this question because we don't know what other possible factors could be affecting that div. Do you have a link to the actual site?

Comment: @Orion I've already - *specifically* - provided isolated / minimal code that you can, at this very moment, test to reproduce my problem. The red and green boxes look nothing like the situation on my website, but are the root problem. The snippet contains only HTML, and the JS script replaces the page with only 2 HTML elements with inline styles.

Comment: That's the problem. That code snippet does not exist in a vacuum. On your website there are a lot of other factors that could possibly contribute to you problem. There's more than one way for code to break. I hope I'm wrong and someone will show up with an answer.

Comment: @Orion I don't understand what you're saying. The code i've provided is as isolated as it gets. The javascript replaces the entire contents of the HTML page, and inserts the 2 DIV elements. There are no external styles referencing or altering them -- only the inline styles.

Comment: Yes, but that is not the case on your website, is it? Meaning, the code that is broken on your site is not isolated so there may be something on your site that is causing the issue.

Comment: @Orion What I'm asking for is the issue with this snippet. I don't see why you 
 would be worrying about my website, as I've already given the issue I'm concerned with, on this post, as an isolated snippet.

Comment: You said above "however on my website it's display like below". So the problem you came here to get help with was on your website. You said you could reproduce the problem with JS, but as you've seen, what fixes the JS doesn't fix your site. As I have said multiple times, this is likely because some other code on your site is breaking it. Your isolated code snippet doesn't help us understand what is broken on your website. I don't know why this is so hard to understand.

Comment: There was text before my !Doctype tag, due to erroneous templating. which invalidated it, and then caused the line height issue

Comment: read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023897/doctype-and-quirk-modes-and-html-5

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your doctype is missing on the collapsed version. Try adding this before your html tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: That's very weird, this fixed the issue... Do you know why? It hasn't resolved the issue in my website, however (which already contains the doctype deceleration).

Comment: Probably because something else on your site is breaking your code. Something not present within your isolated code. This is why isolated code isn't always helpful.

Comment: A missing doctype makes the browser run in quirks mode (backwards compatibility with older browsers) 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode

Comment: Does that mean the line-height stuff isn't supported by older browsers?

Comment: A quick google search can give you the answer for that dude. https://caniuse.com/#search=line-height

Comment: The implementation was different – hence the collapse :-)

Small edit to the comment – it should be backwards compatibility with code written for older browser implementations.